# How can I reproduce this chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to replicate the following chart using `ggplot2`. Any help?

[image]

Here's the data. (`icv` is the LHS bar and `afl` is the RHS bar)

```
library(tibble)

vectorcolors <- c("#967D2D", "#333333", "white")

df <- tibble(
reg = c("Duarte","La Vega","Santiago","Hermanas Mirabal",
         "Sanchez Ramírez","María Trinidad Sánchez","Monseñor Nouel",
         "Puerto Plata","Samaná","Espaillat","Valverde",
         "Santiago Rodríguez","Dajabón","Montecristi"), 
icv = c(69.9, 58.8, 57.1, 54.7, 53.9, 53.3, 49.3,
         48.8, 47.0, 45.4, 44.2, 43.2, 42.8, 42.5),
afl = c(799.3, 800.6, 851.1, 711.7, 839.6, 710.9,
         823.2, 912.7, 605.8, 832.7, 692.0, 858.4,
         758.1, 616.6)
)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://www.onceupondata.com/post/ggplot2-divergent-bars/

Comment: I'd suggest you use two `geom_col()` layers, one with `aes(x = -icv, y = reg)` and one with `aes(x = afl, y= reg)`, with the left one using brown for fill and the right one using white for fill. Then two `geom_text()` for the numbers. And one `geom_text()` for the y axis names, using a pared version of the data with a single value for each. And finally `theme_void()` to erase any axes lines, ticks, labels, or titles. Please demonstrate what you have tried and people will be happy to help where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

colors <- list("sand" = "#967D2D", "gray" = "#333333", "white" = "white")

df <- tibble(
  reg = c("Duarte","La Vega","Santiago","Hermanas Mirabal",
          "Sanchez Ramírez","María Trinidad Sánchez","Monseñor Nouel",
          "Puerto Plata","Samaná","Espaillat","Valverde",
          "Santiago Rodríguez","Dajabón","Montecristi"), 
  icv = c(69.9, 58.8, 57.1, 54.7, 53.9, 53.3, 49.3,
          48.8, 47.0, 45.4, 44.2, 43.2, 42.8, 42.5),
  afl = c(799.3, 800.6, 851.1, 711.7, 839.6, 710.9,
          823.2, 912.7, 605.8, 832.7, 692.0, 858.4,
          758.1, 616.6)
)


df %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = forcats::fct_reorder(reg, icv))) +
  geom_col(aes(x = icv * -1), fill = colors$sand, color = colors$gray) +
  geom_col(aes(x = afl / 10), fill = colors$white, color = colors$gray) +
  geom_text(aes(label = icv, x = icv * -1, hjust = -0.2), color = "white", size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = afl , x = afl / 10, hjust = 1.1), color = colors$gray, size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = reg , x = 1), color = colors$gray, size = 3, hjust = 0) +
  labs(fill = NULL, color = NULL, x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y =  element_text()
  )
```

[image]